# Paypal Sandbox Configuration - Paymentbuttons: missing subscription option

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to test paypal buttons on a website using a paypal sandbox merchant account.

According to the docs i should be able to create a Subscription Button but the option seems to be missing in my Account:

[image: Paypal Button Formular]

Docs:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_step_1/

Since i couldnt find anything about this problem, i thought it might have something to do with my sandbox account settings. So i allready did the following:

- Made sure the account is valid, has a credit card and banking information
- Created a new account with some amount of balance
- Tried to get a paypal plus subscription for the sandbox accounts (did not work)
- Created the button by go to tools-> recurring subscriptions->Create Subscription Button (additonal options): Got redirected and again the option was missing

Is this a problem with my account ? And if so, what do I have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Well i finaly found out that this is kind of a paypal problem. As you can see from the screenshot i have a german paypal account. And if you search the documentation you can find this:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/

> Recurring payments cannot be created for buyers in Germany or China. In this case, you can use reference transactions as an alternate solution.

Im not 100% sure but i think this is the reason why i cant create a subscription button